# Noindent for a paragraph with typewriter font set

Tags: indentation, typewriter

I like to use `noindent` for a paragraph that has its font as `typewriter -tt`.The code snippet is,

```
\noindent
{\tt
\noindent
[cloud-user@sgmanager1 ~]\$ sudo yum list | grep kumo\\
service\_guard.x86\_64\hskip 8em 0.2-0007\hskip 8em @kumo-sg\\
}
```

But still the indent is not removed as,[image]

Comment: `\noindent` has no parameter. I think, you should use something  like `listings` for your request

Comment: In addition `\tt` is outdated... use `\texttt{...}` instead

Comment: It is impossible to say anything given such a fragment (other than the second `\noindent` is not doing anything)  please always post a complete document that demonstrates the effect.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, the answer works. except that my emacs tries to parse the code snippet and an issue is raised http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10554/error-in-font-when-using-code-snippet-inside-lstlisting-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code does not produce an indent

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\tt
\noindent
[cloud-user@sgmanager1 ~]\$ sudo yum list | grep kumo\\
service\_guard.x86\_64\hskip 8em 0.2-0007\hskip 8em @kumo-sg\\
}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

However the second `\noindent` is doing nothing, `\tt` should not be used in LaTeX, and `\\` at the end of a paragraph is always wrong and will produce warnings in the log and bad spacing.  Also I think you want the `~` to be typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
[cloud-user@sgmanager1 ~]$ sudo yum list | grep kumo
service_guard.x86_64 0.2-0007
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: you've lost the wide spaces on the second line; with `verbatim`, just inserting that many spaces (no tabs) in the input should do the job.